# Does MCP Altitude change in the B757/B767 when ALT HOLD is pushed?

Tags: autopilot

I have a question, resulting of a discussion in a different forum: When flying the B757 or B767 and the ALT HOLD button is pushed, will that also change the MCP Altitude to the current altitude, at which the aircraft was, when the button was pushed?

Example: I am flying at FL300, I set my MCP Altitude to 15000 feet. At 18000 feet I push ALT HOLD. Will that change MCP Altitude from 15000 to 18000 feet? I know that some aircraft like the ERJ and the B717 and the B737 do that. I have however never flown a B757 or B767 in real life and I have heard several opinions regarding it.

Also, is this a default setting or this there maybe an operator option to have such a feature fitted? Has there been a refit, where this has been added? Unfortunately the only B757 pilot I know last flew one six years ago, so I don't know.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Cheers,

Ben

Answer (score 2):

No, in a 737 pushing ALT HOLD ***won't*** change the MCP altitude. The aircraft will level off at the altitude where you pushed it, but the MCP altitude won't match that -- which is still a normal place to be, holding one altitude while what's in the MCP window reflects what you're cleared to (perhaps at pilot discretion).

Can't speak to the other Boeings you mentioned, but the same logic would apply.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Maybe I just don't remember well. It has been a long time since I last was in 737 and my TR for it expired. Current operator only maintains ERJ and Airbus.